# locus of the centre of sphere

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d, spheres

Prove that the centres of sphere which touches the lines $$~y=mx , ~z=c ,~ y=-mx , ~z=-c$$
lie upon the conicoid 
               $$mxy+ cz(1+m^2)=0 $$

Comment: please suggest me little ideas and hints

Comment: The given conditions are planes and not lines. Which lines are you referring to?

Comment: sorry ,yeah it must be plane,in question it was written lines and I just copied it,question is in Robert j.t.bell's book in sphere exercise ll ,question no.8